# strip_tags: strip off the messy tags and styles

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace, strip-tags

How can I strip off certain html tags and allow some of them?

For instance,

I want to strip off `span` tags but allow the `span` with underline.

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Text</span>
```

I want to allow `p` but I want to remove any styles or classes inside the `p` for instance,

`<p class="99light">Text</p>` the class inside the p tag should be removed - I just want a clean `p` tag.

The is the line I have so far,

```
strip_tags($content, '<p><a><br><em><strong><ul><li>');
```

Comment: http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

Comment: @naveen, I love whenever someone links to that answer. Should be required reading for anyone who has ever worked with markup. That's a work of art.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You'll need to use an XML/HTML parser to do that:

```
// with DOMDocument it might look something like this.
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $content );
foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( "p" ) as $p )
{
    // removes all attributes from a p tag.
    /*
    foreach( $p->attributes as $attrib )
    {
        $p->removeAttributeNode( $attrib );
    }
    */
    // remove only the style attribute.
    $p->removeAttributeNode( $p->getAttributeNode( "style" ) );
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need full DOM parsing. `strip_tags` will not offer the necessary security and customization. I have used the [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library in the past for this. It does actual parsing and allows you to set whitelists while taking care of malicious inputs and producing valid markup!

By "necessary security" I mean that if you try to write a custom parser you will make a mistake (don't worry, I would too) and by "customization" I mean no built-in solution will let you target only certain tags with certain attributes and values of those attributes. HTMLPurifier is the PHP library solution.