# DOM parser: remove certain attributes only

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, domdocument

How can I use DOM parser to remove **all** attributes in span tags but **except** these two attributes,

`<span style="text-decoration: underline;">cultura</span>` accept

`<span style="text-decoration: line-through;">heart</span>` accept

reject this,

`<span style="font-family: " lang="EN-US">May</span>` accept

Is it possible?

My working code from the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792203/strip-tags-strip-off-the-messy-tags-and-styles) I made,

```
$content = '
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">cultura</span>l <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">heart</span>
<span style="font-family: " lang="EN-US">May</span>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName( "span" ) as $span )
{

    foreach( $span->attributes as $attrib )
    {
        $span->removeAttributeNode( $attrib );
    }


}

$content =  $dom->saveHTML();
```

But this code will remove all attributes inside the `span` tags...

Comment: You're not particularly clear: you want to remove everything except style attributes? or just text-decoration styles?

Comment: sorry. yes all but except text-decoration styles.

Comment: CSS is outside the purview of DOM - you can easily remove all but the style attributes, but you'd need to parse the actual style definitions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it manually.

DOM handles HTML attributes, not CSS properties.

You need to access the *style* attribute, `explode` it's value using `;` as a delimiter, then loop the array looking for the value you want to unset.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is entirely true; the DOM exposes a parsed version of the `style` attribute through the [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) property.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely possible with DOM only. DOM exposes a parsed version of the `style` attribute through the [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) property.

```
$('*').each(function() {
    var s = this.style;
    for (var i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
       if (s[i] != 'font-weight')
           s.removeProperty(s[i]);
});
```

The above code removes every style except `font-weight`.

This uses jQuery's `$('*')` to iterate over every element, but of course you can do it the hard way using just DOM.

Here's a JsFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/NbN3S/

One difficulty with this is that the names appear to be browser-dependent, unfortunately: for example, `text-decoration` is taken apart by Firefox into a bunch of `-moz-*` styles.